# A $\implies$ ¬A. Is my reasoning on the following example correct?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples

[I already asked the question in the Philosophy forum](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/29852/a-implies-%C2%ACa-is-my-reasoning-on-the-following-example-correct), but I haven't gotten any answer, yet. Maybe the mathematicians will be faster:

> Oh, you//
>   anything that rhymes is not true.
>
> **If this statement is true, then it is false.**
>
> First, although it seems very logic to me, is **this** reasoning correct?
>   If so, how do you call this kind of "situation" in logic? Could we say that it is a paradox in the strict definition of the word? Do you have other interesting examples?

So, I had further thoughts on this and discovered, that if you assume that the statement is false, you do not come to any contradiction, because if there exist sentences that rhyme and are true, then it is exactly equivalent to the hypothesis that we have assuming that it is false that "anything that rhymes is not true".

Comment: It is all too common in daily language to interpret "if" as "iff", and even be inconsistent about when to interpret it that way and when not to. You will find no such problems among mathematicians (or at least fewer).

Comment: "how do you call this kind of "situation" in logic?" - **Paradox**.

Comment: @Arthur are you implying that I am confusing these two notions? If so, please be more specific.

Comment: No, not that you are. But the fact that many people would look at that "if" and interpret it as an "iff" is the only reason it even _seems_ paradoxical, which I assume is the reason it was written down. Rather than commenting on your analysis, I was lamenting a quirk of the human mind.

Comment: Yes, I see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the plain old **liar paradox**.

Typically nowadays the liar paradox is presented as a sentence that speaks *only* about its own truth:

> This sentence is false.

but the name is also applied to a sentence that claims that a whole *class* of sentences *which includes itself* are all false. The classical example of that was when Epimenides (who was Cretan) declared, "all Cretans are liars".

This does not in *itself* create an impossible situation as long as there is at least one Cretan who is not a liar (or at least one rhyme that is true), but it would still be quite an iffy sort of reasoning to conclude that truthful Cretans exist *just because Epimenides uttered that particular lie*.

How about

> This sentence as well as the Riemann Hypothesis are both false!

If we accepted Epimenides as proof of the existence of a truthful Cretan, then I've just proved the Riemann Hypothesis ...

---

However, reasoning from $A\to\neg A$ to $\neg A$ is *in itself* completely standard and above-board -- it's even intuitionistically valid. What goes wrong here is not the particular *kind* of reasoning being applied, but the assumption that the original rhyme (which makes claims about its own truth value) can be reasoned about *at all*.

Comment: Re: Epimenides' famous rant, "All Cretans are liars." This will not be an impossible situation as long as (a) Epimenides was lying when he said this, and (b) at least one Cretan, possibly Epimenides himself, at least once told the truth. I like your characterization of the modern liar's paradox: "This sentence is false." IIUC, you are saying it's just a statement of the form $A\to \neg A$. But many will take exception to that as being a gross over simplification. I imagine that entire careers have been built on it.

Answer (score 2):

> $A \to \lnot A$

is not a *contradiction*. If we assume **f** as truth value for $A$, then $\lnot A$ is **f**, and thus the *conditional* becomes :

> **f** $\to$ **t**

which is **t**.

Thus, we have the conclusion that the "correct" answer is : $A$ must be *false*.

In fact :

> $(A \to \lnot A) \to \lnot A$

is a *tautology*, as you can easily check via truth table.

Comment: So a paradox would be of the form:

$(A \to \lnot A) \to \lnot A$
and
$(\lnot A \to A) \to A$

hence we can't say anything about A?

Comment: @derthomas - NO; also $(¬A→A)→A$ is a *tautology*, i.e. always *true*. A *contradiction* (in formal logic) is a sentence always *false*; a [paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradoxes-contemporary-logic/) is something different : Quine defined it as an apparently successful argument having as its conclusion a statement or proposition that seems obviously false or absurd.

Comment: Yes but the sentence "This sentence is false" creates a paradox since its truth implies its falsity AND its falsity implies its truth. Isn't that $((A \to \lnot A) \to \lnot A)$ AND $((\lnot A \to A) \to A)$? I do not consider them seperately, but both being true at the same time.

In addition, if you say "Thus, we have the conclusion that the "correct" answer is : A must be false.", this conclusion is only possible after assuring that A being false does not create another contradiction (i.e. A false implies A true), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement has to be false. As you said, if the statement were true, this would imply that the statement is false which is a contradiction. If the statement false, no contradiction occurs.

More problematic are sentences like **“This sentence is false.”** This can be neither true nor false as always a contradiction will follow. For more information on this, search for Barber paradox.